# Providing a default implementation for Collection conformance prevents additional subscript requirements

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I have a protocol that itself conforms to Swift's `Collection` protocol, and that requires an additional subscript `(Key) -> Value?` returning the value associated with a given key, only if it exists (pretty much like Swift's `Dictionary` does).

```
protocol SearchTree: Collection {
    subscript(key: Int) -> String? { get }
}

struct ConformingTree: SearchTree {
    // Implementation ...
}
```

Now, I'd like to extend it with a default implementation for all `Collection`'s requirements, plus my additional subscript (I guess the implementation specifics are irrelevant, which is why I removed them).

```
protocol SearchTree: Collection {
    subscript(key: Int) -> String? { get }
}

extension SearchTree {
    // MARK: Conformance to Sequence
    func makeIterator() -> AnyIterator<(key: Int, value: String)> { /* ... */ }

    // MARK: Conformance to Collection
    var startIndex: Int { /* ... */ }
    var endIndex: Int { /* ... */ }
    func index(after i: Int) -> Int { /* ... */ }
    subscript(key: Int) -> (key: Int, value: String) { /* ... */ }

    // MARK: Conformance to SearchTree
    subscript(key: Int) -> String? { /* ... */ }
}

struct ConformingTree: SearchTree {
    // Removing previous implementations ...
}
```

Unfortunately, this code will fail with Swift complaining that `ConformingTree` doesn't conforms to `Collection`, unless I keep an implementation for at least one of the subscripts in the conforming type.

```
struct ConformingTree: SearchTree {
    subscript(key: Int) -> String? { /* ... */ }
}
```

I originally thought that Swift was unable to infer the type of the correct subscript in my extension. But this seems unlikely as it eventually can figure out which implementation correspond to which protocol requirement if I push them in the conforming type. As I understand, the return type of `makeIterator()` should force the subscript with signature `(Int) -> (Key, String)` to fulfil `Collection`'s requirement anyway.

Does anyone know what I'm missing here?

Comment: Isn't the problem that the requirement in Collection is couched in terms of its generic placeholders `Self.Index` and `Self.Element`? I don't see where you are resolving those. The compiler isn't going to magically _know_ that these are Int and String; you have to _tell_ it.

Comment: @matt Well, it kind of magically does when the subscripts are declared within the conforming type body. At the very least, `Self.Element` should get resolved as `AnyIterator<(key: Int, value: String)>.Element` because of `makeIterator()`.

Comment: By magically I meant that I expected type inference to work. Type aliases can be omitted in most situations, letting the compiler figure out how associated types should be resolved. I guess I'm just confused as to why type inference works for concrete types and not protocol extensions.

Comment: But that is exactly why, isn't it? You are not an adopter of the protocol. So the compiler has no reason to expect that your method declaration is intended to _satisfy_ a generic requirement. That's not what protocol extensions do. The compiler thinks you are _defining_ a _new_ requirement (and possibly satisfying it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

1. Your declaration of the subscript in the `SearchTree` protocol needs to have `{ get }` after it.
2. `Collection` requires a subscript that returns its `Element`. You have two subscripts, one of which returns a `String?` and one of which returns a `(key: Int, value: String)`, but neither of these is `Element`, which the compiler needs; therefore the type does not conform to `Collection`. If you define `Element` in either your protocol or in the extension, it should compile.

In the protocol:

`associatedtype Element = (key: Int, value: String)`

or:

`associatedtype Element = String?`

Or in the extension:

`typealias Element = (key: Int, value: String)`

or:

`typealias Element = String?`

EDIT:

The above is true for Swift 4; however, for Swift 3, you also need to define `_Element` in addition to `Element`. Copying and pasting your code into a project, the following declaration of the protocol causes everything to compile in Swift 3:

```
protocol SearchTree: Collection {
    associatedtype Element = (key: Int, value: String)
    associatedtype _Element = (key: Int, value: String)

    subscript(key: Int) -> String? { get }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the missing `{get}`. However, I tried both of your suggestions with no more success. As indicated, I do think the compiler should be able to guess the correct signature because `makeIterator()` should already constrain `SearchTree.Element` to be `(key: Int, value: String)` (or more precisely `AnyIterator<(key: Int, value: String)>.Element`).

Comment: I'm guessing you are using Swift 3. I tried it there, and it turns out that in Swift 3 you need to define `_Element` as well as `Element`, a requirement that was removed in Swift 4. The reason that the inference doesn't work here is that the compiler gets confused by the presence of two `subscript(key: Int) -> Something` methods.

Comment: So it was indeed the fact that the type inference failed. I'd be interesting to know why it doesn't when the subscript are defined in the concrete type, but I guess that's another question. Sorry I forgot to mention I was still using Swift 3. Thanks for your help!